# how to disable a tag not having any class?

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with the following codes. I want to disable third `span` that display posts counter that have been viewed by users. How can i fix it?

```css
span i.mdi.mdi-eye:display:none;
```

```html
<div class="post-meta">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span><i class="mdi mdi-eye"></i></span>
</div>
```

Comment: `span i .mdi-eye{display:none;}`

Comment: thank you . but it do's not work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can select every third element with the `nth-child()` selector. Since you don't have more elements in there it works like intended. Better would be to use the `i` class selector though and hide the `i`.

```css
div.post-meta :nth-child(3) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="post-meta">

<span></span>
<span></span>
<span><i class="mdi mdi-eye">10</i></span>

</div>
```

Comment: or using [`last-child`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_last-child.asp) in case your span is always at the bottom. `div.post-meta span:last-child`

Comment: @ChickenSoups Used nth-child because the OP asked "I want to disable third span". I agree that the use of `last-child` is better solution. But I think you should try to avoid css code that breaks down when you change your html structure. Therefore I recommended to use the `i` class selector if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is with the css you have. You have not enclosed the styling with curly braces `{}`

The solution is:

```
span i.mdi.mid-eye {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.post-meta span:not(empty) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="post-meta">

<span></span>
<span></span>
<span><i class="mdi mdi-eye">10</i></span>

</div>
```

or

```css
.post-meta span:last-child {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="post-meta">

<span></span>
<span></span>
<span><i class="mdi mdi-eye">10</i></span>

</div>
```

Comment: Your suggested codes also work . Thank you all very much.

Answer (score 0):

This approach as well works

```
.post-meta span:last-child() {
  display: none;
}
```